# Java: Transform an input number of n length to diff output number of n length

Tags: java, hash

Just after small help.

If a user input a single digit number, output should be single digit number.
No two unique ip number should result in same output

HOwever, for my case ; i am getting same output (9) for two diff ip (4,5) when i tried for single digit number

Also, if the code is run multiple times; the output should always be same for same input

```
package Try;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class Try1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Output " + transformNum("5"));
        
    }       
    
    protected static long setSeed(String ip){
        long hash=0;
        for (char c : ip.toCharArray()) {
            hash=31L*hash+c;
        }
        return hash;
    }
    
    protected static int transformNum(String ip) {
        int iplen=ip.length();
        int upperlmt=Integer.valueOf(String.join("", Collections.nCopies(iplen,"9")))+1;
        int lowerlmt=Integer.valueOf("1" + String.join("", Collections.nCopies(iplen-1,"0")));
        Random rand=new Random(setSeed(ip));
        int transformop = rand.nextInt(upperlmt - lowerlmt) + lowerlmt;
        return transformop;     
    }

}
```

Comment: You must rethink your entire approach: Using a random number (seeded or not) will not guarantee different results for every possible input.

Comment: I thought of one to one mapping between the numbers like change 1 to 4, 2 to 9 etc but that's something very basic. I am more interested in complex logic ,any thoughts will be highly appreciated

Comment: Why not transform as per the 'Caesar' cipher?

Comment: I don't know what you are hoping to achieve. If it's a simple form of format preserving "encryption", which is reversible, you should probably use a table as you suggest, perhaps ROT5 for each digit.